# How to index and make multiple matches across multiple columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
 Animal      Where    Quantity
 Giraffe     Wild     22
 Lion        Zoo      87
 Tiger       Zoo      56
 Giraffe     Zoo      15
 Elephant    Wild     94
 Tiger       Wild     47
 Lion        Wild     45
 Elephant    Zoo      12
 Tiger       Zoo      48
```

I need to return all quantities of Tiger, but only the ones in a Zoo, and I need to list those quantities on different cells in a column. I should be able to easily change the query from Tiger to any other animal.

Output should looks something like this:

```
Get the quantities of Tigers that live in a Zoo:
 Tiger
  56        
  48

Get the quantities of Lions that live in the Wild:
 Lions
  94
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect? Table with filters or pivot might be good way to solve this.

Comment: I have updated with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

misunderstood question

so you are going to have two cells somewhere that are going to represent your criteria. Lets call it cells D1 for animal type and cell D2 for location.

You are then going to use a combination of the following formulas:  INDEX and AGGREGATE.

Lets start with AGGREGATE.  Use it to build a list of row numbers that match the criteria your a looking for.

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(range of the first column of your table)/((range1=criteria1)*(range2=criteria2)*...*(rangeN=criteriaN)),row(A1))
```

- 15 tells AGGREGATE to generate a list sorted in ascending order.
- 6 tells AGGREGATE to exclude any errors from the list.
- ROW() gives us the row number we are working with dividing by the criteria will only allow results where all criteria are true to be a valid list entry. Any False results will result in a divide by zero error and thus
  exluding the ROW() from the list of results.
- ROW(A1) tells AGGREGATE to return the Nth number in the list.  so ROW(A1) will act as a counter as the formula is dragged down.  It will increase by 1 for each row its copied to.

A couple of important things to note.  AGGREGATE performs array like calculations.  As such avoid full column references within the aggregate function.  Large ranges within an array calculation can slow down your computer. Marke sure you lock your reference ranges with $ to prevent them from changing as you copy unless it is something you want to change such as row(A1)

So now you know how to get a list of row numbers for the answers you want.  You now want to embed this information into an INDEX formula:

```
INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(...))
```

Repeat this for each column of information you want to pull updating the A:A part for where you want to pull the information from.

Proof of concept

[image: POC]

in the the image I wrapped the whole formula in an IFERROR function to display "" when nothing is found.  Handy for when you copy down more rows than there are results.

Comment: Thank you! This gives an accurate TOTAL, but I need the individual quantities, each in it's own cell

Comment: That's perfect! I've spent almost 2 weeks trying to figure this out on my own. I can't thank you enough!